# Como dizer centro de custo no plural (em português-brasileiro)?

Tags: português-brasileiro, substantivos

Como dizer corretamente **centro de custo** no plural?

Antes que me perguntem, sim, refere-se ao centro de custo relativo à área contábil.

Comment: Rodrigo, isso vai depender do contexto do uso deste termo.

Comment: Acho que não. Só existe uma forma do plural nesse caso.

Answer (score 5):

> centro de custo no plural é igual que casa de campo. Só se flexiona o
>   premeiro termo.
>
> centros de custo e casas de campo

***de custo*** e ***de campo*** funcionam como adjetivos. Por isso são invariáveis.

[um exemplo de centros de custo em contexto](https://www.siteware.com.br/metodologias/centro-de-custo-de-uma-empresa/)

Para fechar o assunto, a regra é essa:

[substantivos compostos intermediados por elemento de ligação](http://www.biaobresil.com/palavras-compostas-definicao-exemplos-plural/)

"Plural: só flexiona o primeiro termo.   Exemplos: pães de ló, luas de mel, mãos de obra."

Comment: Lambie, o teu segundo link está partido, vou removê-lo.

Comment: Já concertei o link. Agora funciona. Por favor, não muda os textos amarelados.