# Qual o plural de "curva de nível" para mais de um nível?

Tags: número-gramatical, concordância, substantivos

Em matemática, existe o conceito de **curva de nível** com plural **curvas de nível**.

- As curvas de nível descrevem objetos geométricos.
- O nível é especificado por um valor numérico.

Exemplo: Se para o nível 7 a curva de nível descreve uma reta, dizemos

1. **A curva de nível 7 é uma reta.**

Suponha que, para o nível 8, a curva também seja uma reta. Então, vamos dizer

2. **A curva de nível 8 é uma reta.**

Se eu quiser expressar as informações das frases 1 e 2 numa única frase, qual das opções abaixo é a correta?

3. **As *curvas de nível* 7 e 8 são retas.**
4. **As *curvas de níveis* 7 e 8 são retas.**

Ou seja: "nível" deve ficar no singular pra concordar com o plural "curvas de nível" ou deve  ficar no plural pra concordar com "7 e 8"?

Comment: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/como-dizer-centro-de-custo-no-plural-em-portugu%c3%aas-brasileiro/5935#5935

Comment: @Lambie No caso da minha pergunta, a parte que funciona como adjetivo não incluiria dois adjetivos (nível 7 e nível 8)? Assim, não deveria ficar níveis 7 e 8? Será que nessa construção a palavra deixa de ser entendida como substantivo composto?

Comment: Não. As curvas tem um nível. O nível chamada 7 ou 8,, por exemplo. A 3) está certa na minha opinião.

Comment: Note também: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/3550/2764 (Plural de substantivos compostos: e.g. por que “cavalos-vapor” mas “decretos-leis”?) e também https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/9320/2764 (Qual é o plural de "função potência"?). Desta última posso repetir: "Apenas o primeiro elemento vai para o plural [...] [quando] o segundo elemento limita o sentido do primeiro", assim como geralmente se diz "duas cadeiras de madeira" e não "duas cadeiras de madeiras".